# Free And Open Source Software Tools to orthorectify Pleiades imagery

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, open-source-gis

Are there Free And Open Source Software Tools to orthorectify Pleiades, Worldview And Quickbird imagery as we do with COST tools such as ERDAS Imagine, PCI, ENVI, etc.?

Comment: Perhaps only partly duplicate. This question handles especially satellite images which need special tools. OSSIM will be on the list but I am not sure about the others. Perhaps GRASS and Opticks.

Comment: my answer in the duplicate question (OTB) is completely valid for Pleiades.